# Does the xxx.com blacklist not apply to question titles?

Tags: discussion, content-blocklist

I just [edited a question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24548428/revisions) to remove a reference to `xxx.com` from the title. The question already used `example.com` in the body. I would guess that the asker originally used `xxx.com` in both places, was forced to edit the body before posting, but neglected to edit the title. Should the system block this porn domain in the title too?

Comment: It does not really hurt in the title, as you cannot just click it and land on a NSFW site. Might be fodder for the low-quality-detector though.

Comment: I think this question just answered the question.

Comment: It's not that it doesn't match the title, it's that the URL is only blocked if it is preceded by an `http://` (which would make it clickable in a post body). This is the actual blacklist currently being used: `http://(www\.)?(xxx|xyz|abc|site|mysite|mydomain)\.(com|org|net)`